# Show form post information from html with jersey

Tags: java, html, web-services, jsp, jersey

I have been using jersey to lean how to write my own rest service. After a user has submitted their name how can I load an html or jsp page to show them what they have entered? Everything is working great so far but I cant for the life of me find out how to display to the user their information within a friendly manner. Any tips? I've searched the internet and all I can find is application tutorials.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String post(@FormParam("name") String name) {
    submitted = name;
       System.out.println(submitted);
         return submitted; // displays name in browser

}
```

I Know I can do something like this:

```
String message = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">"+
        "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" dir=\"ltr\" lang=\"de-DE\">" +
        "<div style=\"padding-left:20px; height:200px; width:800px; font-size:20px;\">" +
            "<p>" +
                "<h1 style=\"color:#313e7d\">" +
                    "Your name is " + submitted
                "</h1>" +
            "</p>"+
            "<img src=\"/images/img_logo.gif\" height=\"51\" width=\"537\"/>"+
        "</div>"+
        "</html>";
```

I would rather not, anyway I can link to an html file?

Comment: http://blog.docuverse.com/2009/08/04/using-jsp-with-jersey-jax-rs-implementation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a [`Viewable`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/mvc/Viewable.html) object that links to an HTML file that displays the name you get from the server. In your case, you can have another method that uses GET:

```
@GET
@Path("name")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Viewable displayForm() {
    return new Viewable("/display_name.html");
}
```

The HTML file `display_name.html` can have some AJAX code to get the resource (submitted name) from the path `http://example.com/context/name`.